# django/wagtail : why my page doesnt pass along pk variable?

Tags: reactjs, django, wagtail

I am trying to get the preview work in wagtail with a react frontend and djangorestframework serving it.

I have the preview working correctly by changing manually the url passed along and putting the right `pk` identifier which is initially `None`.

My question is why does the `pk` in the PostPage class in the get_preview_url function is not correctly set? I dont see where it comes from

Here is the code

```
class PostPage(BasePage):
    serializer_class = "blog.serializers.PostPageSerializer"

    header_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )

    body = StreamField(BodyBlock(), blank=True)

    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through="blog.PostPageTag", blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel("header_image"),
        InlinePanel("categories", label="category"),
        FieldPanel("tags"),
        StreamFieldPanel("body"),
    ]

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('title'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]
    api_fields = ( 
    APIField(
    "header_image_url",
    serializer=ImageRenditionField("max-1000x800", source="header_image"), 
    ),
    "body",
    APIField("owner"),
    APIField("api_categories", serializer=CategoryField(source="categories")),#check if categories retrieved
    APIField("api_tags", serializer=TagField(source="tags")), 
    #APIField("pub_date",serializer=DateTimeField(format="%d %B %Y", source="first_published_at")),
    )
    def get_preview_url(self, token): 
        return urllib.parse.urljoin(self.get_client_root_url(), 
                                    f"post/{self.pk}/"
                                    + "?"
                                    + urllib.parse.urlencode({"content_type": self.get_content_type_str(), "token": token}),
                                    )
    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        return HttpResponseRedirect(urllib.parse.urljoin(self.get_client_root_url(), f"/post/{self.pk}") )
```

And here is the BasePage class which is being inherited in PostPage:

```
class BasePage(HeadlessPreviewMixin, Page):

    serializer_class = None

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_component_data(self):
        if not self.serializer_class:
            raise Exception(f'serializer_class is not set {self.__class__.__name__}')

        serializer_class = import_string(self.serializer_class)

        return {
            'page_type': self.__class__.__name__,
            'page_content': serializer_class(self).data
        }

    def categories_list(self, context):
        categories = BlogCategory.objects.all()

        blog_page = context['blog_page']
        data = [{
            'name': category.name,
            'slug': category.slug,
            'url': blog_page.url + blog_page.reverse_subpage(
                "post_by_category",
                args=(
                    category.slug,
                )
            )
        } for category in categories]

        return data

    def tags_list(self, context):
        tags = Tag.objects.all()

        blog_page = context['blog_page']
        data = [{
            'name': tag.name,
            'slug': tag.slug,
            'url': blog_page.url + blog_page.reverse_subpage(
                "post_by_tag",
                args=(
                    tag.slug,
                )
            )
        } for tag in tags]

        return data

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['page_component'] = self.get_component_data()

        if 'blog_page' not in context:
            context['blog_page'] = BlogPage.objects.first()
        context['page_component']['categories_list'] = self.categories_list(context)
        context['page_component']['tags_list'] = self.tags_list(context)
        return context

    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.content_type == 'application/json':
            context = self.get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return JsonResponse(context['page_component'])
        else:
            full_path = request.get_full_path()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urllib.parse.urljoin(settings.REACT_APP_BASE, full_path))
```

I dont see any pk in both classes, so i guess it comes from Page or HeadlessPreviewMixin class, but I dont know where to look to investigate. I usually am more accustomed to see the pk in my React code in the props or state of components, but i dont see how it is transferred to a django python variable.

Where can i investigate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value for `pk` will be coming from Page since the page `id` field is the primary key. However, until the page is saved, there won't be a value for id. The id is created from your database's sequence or auto-increment field during the page save process.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. But when i say i change manually the pk, i dont use a pk of a published page, i use the pk created for the preview...

Comment: I don't know how you "use the pk created for the preview". Your `def get_preview_url` method is in PostPage so self.pk there is the id from the wagtailcore_page table.

The code you show doesn't match the example code from https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-headless-preview#example Perhaps you could try that code - along with appropriate options from the Configuration section. I think one or more of those should take care of the `serve` override in your BasePage model